# Still Not Gettiing The Error Solved E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am new to Kotlin, i have been working on this application and before connecting the API, i was able to view the sample data applied. After the connection i get error

> E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Below is my fragment

```
package com.example.testapp.ui.complaints

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.testapp.R
import com.example.testapp.ui.ApiData.ApiDataEndPoints
import com.example.testapp.ui.ApiData.Complaints
import com.example.testapp.ui.ApiData.ServiceBuilder
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_complaints.*
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response

class ComplaintsFragment: Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        //inflating the layout for this fragment
        //the fragment class calls our fragment layout
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_complaints, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        //creating a call of the ApiEndPoints interface
        val request = ServiceBuilder.buildService(ApiDataEndPoints::class.java)

        val call = request.getComplaints(getString(R.string.api_key))

        call.enqueue(object : Callback<Complaints> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Complaints>, response: Response<Complaints>){
                if(response.isSuccessful){
                    progress_bar.visibility = View.GONE

                    text_complaints.apply{
                        setHasFixedSize(true)
                        // set the LinearLayoutManager to handle the Android
                        //Recyclerview behavior
                        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireActivity()) //removed activity and put requireActivity()
                        // set the custom adapter to the RecyclerView
                        adapter = ComplaintsAdapter(response.body()!!.results)
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Complaints>,t: Throwable){
                Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "${t.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

i've searched over the internet but all the solutions I'm getting there are not helping me.

Comment: @Abhimanyu it is, it's inside the apply block

Answer (score 2):

`request.getComplaints` is an asynchronous callback, which may be delayed after layout inflating.

You could set the adapter inside `OnCreate` method or other proper place, and just update the adapter using `notifyDataSetChanged()` within above callback.

Comment: How can i do this please?